# Add a link to php

Tags: php, wordpress

can you please help me how to add a link to php code.

Thing is that I am using a BMI calculator for wordpress and I want to add a link next to a result number.

I know html, but not php...

one slip of a php code where I want to have a link is:

```
    $theme = $attrs['theme'] ?: 'default';
    $resultText = $attrs['result'] ?: 'Your BMI is %bmi% ';
        $resultText = str_replace('%bmi%', '<span class="bmi-number"></span>', $resultText);
```

-> I would like to have a link right next to the bmi result number -> 'Your BMI is %bmi% '

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the outputted HTML suppose to be? Can't you just do `Your BMI is <a href="link">%bmi%</a>` in the first `$resultText` assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this

```
$BMI = 123;
$resultText = "Your BMI is <a href='YOUR_LINK_HERE'>".$BMI."</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for answers guys... but %bmi% is some kind of a warible, because on the page I put it like a shortcode:  
[bmi theme="default" heightPlaceholder="Height" submit="Calculate" result="BMI indeks  %bmi%"] 

This %bmi% calculates from the form... in the form you put your weight and height and than you get an answer, you can check it out here on the test page: http://legionargym.si/testna-stran/

Answer (score 0):

```
$BMI = 'click here'; //There can be some code here
$resultText = "Your BMI is <a href='http://your_link.com'>$BMI</a> ";
echo $resultText;
```

Comment: `$BMI` is not a variable (if it were it wouldn't work in single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers guys... but %bmi% is some kind of a varible, because on the page I put a shortcode:
[bmi theme="default" heightPlaceholder="Height" submit="Calculate" result="BMI indeks  %bmi%"]

This %bmi% calculates from the form... in the form you put your weight and height and than you get an answer, you can check it out here on the test page: http://legionargym.si/testna-stran/

slide down and see Calculate your BMI

Link to php file is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/441444/BMIphpcode.txt

```
    $crawlers_agents = strtolower('Bloglines subscriber|Dumbot|Sosoimagespider|QihooBot|FAST-WebCrawler|Superdownloads Spiderman|LinkWalker|msnbot|ASPSeek|WebAlta Crawler|Lycos|FeedFetcher-Google|Yahoo|YoudaoBot|AdsBot-Google|Googlebot|Scooter|Gigabot|Charlotte|eStyle|AcioRobot|GeonaBot|msnbot-media|Baidu|CocoCrawler|Google|Charlotte t|Yahoo! Slurp China|Sogou web spider|YodaoBot|MSRBOT|AbachoBOT|Sogou head spider|AltaVista|IDBot|Sosospider|Yahoo! Slurp|Java VM|DotBot|LiteFinder|Yeti|Rambler|Scrubby|Baiduspider|accoona');
    $crawlers = explode("|", $crawlers_agents);
    foreach($crawlers as $crawler) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), trim($crawler)) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function __construct() {
    if (!$this->is_bot()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('bmi-calculator-shortcode-styles', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'bmi-calculator-shortcode.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('bmi-calculator-shortcode-scripts', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'bmi-calculator-shortcode.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}

public function processShortcode($attrs) {
    $metricText = $attrs['metric'] ?: 'Metrične merske enote';
    $imperialText = $attrs['imperial'] ?: 'Imperične merske enote';
    $heightText = $attrs['height'] ?: 'Vaša višina';
    $weightText = $attrs['weight'] ?: 'Vaša teža';
    $heightPlaceholder = $attrs['heightPlaceholder'] ?: 'Višina';
    $weightPlaceholder = $attrs['weightPlaceholder'] ?: 'Teža';
    $submitText = $attrs['submit'] ?: 'Submit';
    $theme = $attrs['theme'] ?: 'default';
    $resultText = $attrs['result'] ?: 'Your BMI is %bmi% ';
        $resultText = str_replace('%bmi%', '<span class="bmi-number"></span>', $resultText);

    $out = <<<HEREDOC
```